# Why can't I press UP, LEFT, and SPACE at the same time in Ursina?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina

I have some problems while running my code.

I want my cube to jump and move at the same time.

When I press `up arrow` and `left arrow` and then press `space`, the jumping function bound with `space` doesn't work

But it works well while pressing other keys together like `left arrow` and `down arrow`.

And it also works when I change `arrows` into `wasd`.

Is it a bug in ursina or just I made some mistakes ?

My code:

```
import ursina as us

app = us.Ursina()

class Player(us.Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            parent=us.scene,
            model='cube',
            position=(0, -1, 5),
            rotation=(0, 45, 0),
            texture='white_cube',
            color=us.color.azure,
            )
        us.camera.position = (0, 0, 0)
        us.camera.rotation = (0, -1, 0)
        
        self.gravity = 0.01
        self.strength = 0.2
        self.v = None
        
    def update(self):
        if us.held_keys['up arrow']:
            self.position += self.forward * us.time.dt
        if us.held_keys['down arrow']:
            self.position += self.back * us.time.dt
        if us.held_keys['right arrow']:
            self.position += self.right * us.time.dt
        if us.held_keys['left arrow']:
            self.position += self.left * us.time.dt
        
        if us.held_keys['space']:
            self.jump()
        
        if self.v != None:
            self.v -= self.gravity
            if self.v > -self.strength:
                self.position += (0, self.v, 0)
            else:
                self.v = None
        
        
    def jump(self):
        if self.v == None:
            self.v = self.strength
        

player = Player()
us.Sky()

app.run()
```

Comment: That sounds like you just have a cruddy keyboard with bad [rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)).

Comment: but it's ok with left, down, and space together

Comment: I also tried wasd and it's ok, is it still my keyboard's problem ?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me, any combination of arrows and space moves and jumps simultaneously

Comment: ok it sounds like I have to change a keyboard

Comment: It works for me everywhere except for windows computers.